# Using the getAccuracy wrong

Tags: java, android, geolocation

I'm building a location based application and I would like to avoid from this kind of location: "Tel Aviv, Tel Aviv, Israel" which is very not accurate.

I use the following condition before using a location:

```
if(!(this.location == null || this.location.getAccuracy() > 700))
    // use the location
```

But I keep getting this locations (Tel Aviv, Tel Aviv, Israel), and Tel Aviv is not small enough to pass this condition.

I'm missing something? What's wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't specified a couple of parameters involved but I'll give it a try.

The exact `Location` parameters depend on the source of that particular `Location`, i.e. how it was obtained and using what geolocation source(s). For example:

- If you use GPS, the `Location` will have reliable `accuracy` values.
- If you use cellular network radio stations (BTS), the accuracy you'll receive will be limited to the database of BTS around the world, their location and range.
- If you use Wi-Fi networks and their reported signal strength, the accuracy will depend on the quality of the database of the Wi-Fi networks. Unfortunately such databases are not cheap to maintain and create. For example Google buys such databases and uses Google Street View cars for scanning such networks.
- If you use localization based on public IP address, your accuracy will be limited to a town, because that is the most accurate information contained in IANA IP address space registry. Also, it can be fooled by using a proxy servers.

The accuracy you'll receive from a location service represents a distance (in meters) from the reported location in which the device is likely to be in the moment the location was obtained.

So (if I understand your question correctly), I presume your using a low-accuracy method of obtaining current device location. You simply must switch to a source of `Location` with greater accuracy.

Please also note that the location-acquiring method (i.e. the service used to find the location as described above) used by the location service *might actually not be able to provide accuracy* for returned `Location`. To understand what I mean by that consider a following scenario and their two outcomes - note that they both come from the same locating method based on Wi-Fi networks:

1. You are in range of several Wi-Fi networks. You ask the location service about device location. All Wi-Fi networks in range happen to be in location service DB. The location service is thus able to get your location with decent accuracy.
2. You are in range of several Wi-Fi networks. However, none of them happens to be well known to location service in that their origin (town) is known, but their exact location and range is not known. In that case the location service is able to tell you which country/town you are in, but has no idea on your precise location. In turn, location service can give you a location with no accuracy.

You must make yourself prepared for such an occasion by testing if the accuracy is available at all. You can do this by issuing `Location.hasAccuracy()`. If the returned value is `false`, you *can't* call `Location.getAccuracy()` (actually you can, but beware - it'll return `0`!). So, your condition should be more like:

```
if (this.location != null && this.location.hasAccuracy() && this.location.getAccuracy() < 700) {
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer! I'm using the gps and the network providers since my user might be indoor and outdoor. I guess that the locations I'm speaking about generated by the network provider. But I still don't understand how come it pass my condition..city level accuracy is MUCH bigger then 700. maybe the answer is what you said about " the location service might actually not be able to provide accuracy for returned Location" what does that mean? it's very not accurate so it doesn't has an accurate or it's just a bug?

Comment: It means just that. It's not a bug! Remember to always check if `Location.hasAccuracy()` is `true` before comparing `getAccuracy()` to anything. You can't make an assumption that a location based on available networks will have an accuracy larger than `700`. Consider that Google uses their DBs of network locations to give you a more accurate location. What is *your purpose* of this check? If you want to know whether the location arrived based on networks available, check the `Location.getProvider()` value.

Comment: @ImriPersiado I've also updated the answer to contain an example of why once you can get a location with accuracy and on the second run - without accuracy from the same location provider.

Comment: Thank you, I check it because my app sends to the db every 5 min the user location and if the location is not accurate I would like to ignore it and stick with the old one.

Comment: @ImriPersiado sure, that's a common thing to do and that's the purpose of `hasAccuracy()` - all location providers which support accuracy set it to `true` and set accuracy of the location to a valid value. So I think the check in the end of the answer is exactly what you need :)

Comment: Yes. And again thank you for your detailed comments it's not obvious.